# Problem with responsiveness for small screens

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive

I'm working on an image upload component, and the design breaks when I put iphone 5 / se
But my css are breaking out, I want to force the design to respect the limits, iphone 6 and others are good, but when I change to the iphone 5, well, the print says everything.

This is the CSS code:

```
import { fontTitle, fontSizeInput, gradient, shadow, primaryColor, grayColor3, grayColor4 } from './theme'

export const

dropzone = {
    display: 'grid',
    margin: 'auto',
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyItems: 'center',
    gridRowGap: '15px',
    border: `2px dashed ${grayColor3}`,
    borderRadius: '6px',
    color: primaryColor,
    textAlign: 'center',

},

instructions = {
    marginTop: '20px'
},

button = {
    display: 'block', // necessary for link version
    WebkitAppearance: 'none',
    WebkitTapHighlightColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    MozAppearance: 'none',
    outline: 'none',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    width: '90%',
    padding: '10px 0px',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '20px',
    fontFamily: fontTitle,
    fontSize: fontSizeInput,
    color: '#FFF',
    background: gradient,
    boxShadow: `${shadow}`
},

btnDisabled = {
    ...button,
    cursor: 'initial',
    color: primaryColor,
    background: 'none',
    backgroundColor: grayColor4,
    boxShadow: 'none'
},

input = {
    opacity: 0
},

styleTag = `
    .dropzone {
        height: 100%;
        height: -webkit-fill-available;
        height: -moz-available;
    }
`
```

This is the print of how it looks:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you change /  remove `width: '90%',`? That seems possibly the cause. That or there's another set of styles for `dropzone` that include padding, or `button` that has `width`. It's worth inspecting those.

Comment: Hi Luke!
It's not that :/